# How to access data in the previous activity?

Tags: java, android

Using `StartActivity` i reached SecondActivity from FirstActivity..Now i want to access object declared in the previous activity.

Is there any obvious mechanisms that i am missing.I cant use Parceable on the object(DropboxAPI) i want to pass since i do not have its source(i can't make it parceable).

Can i pass `FirstActivity.this` since i can make it Parceable using an intent?or like

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("MyClass",FirstActivity.this);
    startActivity (intent);

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.android.AndroidAuthSession;

import android.app.Application;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
public class temp extends Application {

    DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;
    public void onCreate() {  
        super.onCreate();  
    }

    temp(DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> Api)
    {
        mApi=Api;
    }
    public DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> getName() {    
        return mApi;  
} 
    public void setName(DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> dropboxclient) {  
        this.mApi = dropboxclient;  
}
}
```

Code in first class:

```
t = (temp)getApplication();
                t.setName(mApi);
                //basket.putParcelable("key", MCActivity.this);
                Intent intent=new Intent(MCActivity.this,DownActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("MyClass",t);
                startActivity (intent);
```

Code in Second class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bun) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(bun);
    setContentView(R.layout.download);
    mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    //Bundle gotit=getIntent().getExtras();
    t = (temp)getApplication();
    int i=2;
    i=5;
    dApi=t.getName();
}
```

Logcat:

```
06-28 02:24:31.979: I/System.out(729): debugger has settled (1308)
06-28 02:25:08.387: D/AndroidRuntime(729): Shutting down VM
06-28 02:25:08.387: W/dalvikvm(729): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at cloud.mobile.MCActivity$3.onClick(MCActivity.java:164)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-28 02:25:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

try using Application  class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    //Variable we want to share to All Activities in Application

    private DropboxClient dropboxclient;  

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() {  
            super.onCreate();  

    }  
    //Getter Method
    public DropboxClient getName() {    
            return dropboxclient;  
    }  
    //Setter Method
    public void setName(DropboxClient dropboxclient) {  
            this.dropboxclient = dropboxclient;  
    }  
}
```

In MyFirstActivity Activity:

```
private MyApplication app;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        app = (MyApplication)getApplication();  //Get  Application
        app.setName(dropboxclient);
        Intent intent = new Intent(); 
        intent.setClass(this, MySecondActivity.class);  
        startActivity(intent);
```

In MySecondActivity Activity:

```
private MyApplication app;  
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
            app = (MyApplication)getApplication();  //Get  Application
            DropboxClient dropboxclient=app.getName();//Access global value
```

Comment: In debug mode app = (MyApplication)getApplication(); is getting error..

06-28 02:06:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(699): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application

Comment: @AmelJose :and make sure you have add your Application Class in manifast.xml

Comment: i sorry but will this do for the manifest?
         <application android:name=".temp">
             </application>

Comment: temp is the name of Application class

Comment: if you have any problem to implement Application class then just download this easy example https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/Applicationclass.rar?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: still having the problem..i hav edited the post with all the codes i used..and logcat

Comment: try using     public void onCreate() {  
        super.onCreate();  
  setName(new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>); //Initialize global variables 
    }

Comment: i have invite u on chat plz join then we will discussion all issues

Answer (score 1):

do the following,

start the activity with `startActivityForResult()`

```
startActivityForResult(0, MyActivity.class);
```

before your started activity finished, in the started activity, create an intent, and put whatever data you want to pass back as extras in the intent. now call `setResult(..., intent)`;

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("myKey", myVal);
setResult(0, resultIntent);
```

in your starting activity, implement `onActivityResult()`, and handle the result of the started activity. you will be passed an `Intent`, which is the intent where you added extras in the started activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //TODO handle here. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend `Application` class and declare and initialize your cross activity objects in that class and write getters for those objects.

now using following code in an activty, you can access those Objects.

```
getApplication().getMyObject().doSomeAction();
```

remember, you will have to modifiy your androidManifest.xml to tell android about your extended application class.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
    Using StartActivityforResult there data moveback to Second Activity to First Activity

One Example there data move to second Activity to first Activity- 
      http://micropilot.tistory.com/1577